# Get dynamically value of a column using plpgsql

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I create a function that returns the value of a field when the id is given :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_dcteam(id int) RETURNS text
AS $$
#print_strict_params on
DECLARE
dc_team text;
BEGIN
    SELECT monitoring_table.dc_team INTO STRICT dc_team
        FROM monitoring_table WHERE monitoring_table.id = get_dcteam.id;
    RETURN dc_team;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I call it this way :

```
select * from get_dcteam((select id from monitoring_table where id=30))
```

What I want to do is call the function  dynamically. I don't want to precise a known id.
How can I do this?

Comment: This a SQL question, better suited to [dba.se]

Answer (score 0):

Don't ever call it like that. Because it returns a single value (`RETURNS text`) Call it like this instead, it's cleaner.

```
SELECT id, get_dcteam(id)
FROM monitoring_table
WHERE id = 30;
```

Now if you want it for more id's remove the WHERE Clause.

```
SELECT id, get_dcteam(id)
FROM monitoring_table;
```

Also you should probably rewrite that to use regular SQL, as it may be inlined.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_dcteam(id int)
RETURNS text
AS $$
    SELECT monitoring_table.dc_team
    FROM monitoring_table
    WHERE monitoring_table.id = get_dcteam.id;
$$ LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE;
```

But one step further, I'd just delete the function entirely. It's basic SQL and it's just going to slow you down. Look at what you're doing: `get_dcteam` is querying `monitoring_table`, and you're calling it on a query that is already visiting that table! This will be much faster and clearer:

```
SELECT id, dc_team
FROM monitoring_table
WHERE id = 30;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. This call will give me several rows. What I  Want is use this function in a where clause of an other one, but without passing the id in parameters.